# Using if statement if not multiple

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I want to create a 5x5 array of '*' with a hashtag in the center instead of '*', but only when the user inputs either 'a' or 'b.' On the area I marked "RIGHT HERE" it doesn't work unless its ONLY 'a' / ONLY 'b', so what do I do? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


while (true){

///Variables:

char array[4][4]; //Playing field 5x5
char direc; //Direction player moves




for (int x = 0; x <=4; x++){

    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++){

        array[x][y] = '_';
    if (direc != 'a' || 'b'){ ///RIGHT HERE!
        array[2][2] = '#';
    }

        cout << array[x][y]; //Starts printing Board

        if (y == 4){
        cout << endl; //Cuts to next line on print if 4 in a column row
    }

}
}

cin >> direc;
cin.get();




}

}
```

Comment: Bounds of your array are 0 to 3.

Comment: There are too many problems with the shown code. For starters, your computer always runs things from the beginning to the end. Checking `direc` before even asking for input is not going to work. Arrays being out of bounds. Broken boolean logic. Just three obvious problems, from the first look.

Comment: `direc != 'a' || 'b'` is equivalent to `(direc != 'a') || 'b'`, which is tautological because 'b' is a non-zero integer and is taken to mean `true`

Answer (score 1):

Did not check the required logic of your statement or of the other parts of your program, but your marked statement should be written as

```
(direc != 'a' || direct != 'b')
```

Your statement `(direc != 'a' || 'b')` will always evaluate to true, since `'b'`  as the second operand of the logical or operator `||` is an integer value > 0 (representing character `b` in some encoding) and therefore treated as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil mentioned in the comment, ur 5x5 field is in fact 4x4, so u are only able to access array[0][0] up to array[3][3], while your X and Y are 4 at some point. You should use this instead:

```
char array[5][5]
```

so that u can access your array up to index 4

Answer (score 0):

hope that helps you

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ///Variables:

char array[5][5]; //Playing field 5x5
char direc; //Direction player moves
char player;

while (true) {

    //get direc
    cin >> direc;
    cout << direc << "\n";
    if (direc == 'a' || direc == 'b') { ///RIGHT HERE!
        player = '_';
    }
    else {
        player = '#';
    }

    for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++) {
            array[x][y] = '_';
            if (x == 2 && y == 2) {
                array[x][y] = player;
            }
            cout << array[x][y]; //Starts printing Board
            if (y == 4) {
                cout << endl; //Cuts to next line on print if 4 in a column row
            }

        }
    }

}

}
```